# Infinite recursion in PHP with new self()

Tags: php, class, oop, recursion

I now have this class for strings (type hinting and because it's funny):

```
/**
 * A String class for string type hinting in functions
 */
class string {

    /**
     * The value
     * @var string
     */
    public $string;

    /**
     * makes a string out of a string... georgous..
     * @param string $string
     */
    public function __construct($string) {
        if(!is_string($string)):
            return false;
        endif;
        $this->string = new self($string);
    }

    /**
     * magic toString method ;)
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->string;
    }

    /**
     * Serializer
     * @return array
     */
    public function __sleep() {
        return ['string'];
    }

    /**
     * array maker
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray() {
        return [$this->string];
    }

    /**
     * split a string
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function splitstr() {
        return explode("", $this->string);
    }
}
```

When I do `$this->string = new self($string);`, PHP should create a never ending ammount of recursions. This would then look like:

```
new string("test) {
    $string = new string("test") {
        $string = new string("test") {
            $string = new string("test") ... AND SO ON FOREVER
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question:
Why is PHP resetting the network connection (PHP and Apache2) when executing this?

Comment: I have now tested this without Apache. It's working normal until I get a memory error from bash and PHP ends with 139.

Comment: I'm only wondering why PHP doesn't catch something like this as an error...

Comment: It actually does `xdebug.max_nesting_level` is the depth after you are getting an exception. But again....why? this code is crap :D sorry

Comment: I know, that it's not usful for anything, but I'm happy finding this little "bug"...

Comment: I think it could be, that the proper bug is in var_dump'ing an instance of it ... xD

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * makes a string out of a string... georgous..
 * @param string $string
 */
public function __construct($string) {
    if(!is_string($string)):
        return false;
    endif;
    $this->string = new self($string);
}
```

is infinity rekusive

you can try

```
 !self::$string AND self::$string = new self($string);
```

but i dont thing that helps out here.

Why in the first place do you make `new self()`

Lookup what Single Instance of a Class in PHP means. Thats the only needfull way you have to `new self()` in php.

and there is no `type hinting` in your code

```
class A {
   function typeHintingFunction(string $sting){

   }
}
```

`explode($this->string);` misses one args

Holps that helps a little

Comment: I know Singletons and I'm using them. But I found it funny to do some strange things like making infinite recursion of a class in it. The whole file I'm working on has more than 1200 lines. I want to use the type hintig elsewhere in some other classes. `explode($this->string);` would usually only work if I used `$this->string =$string;`. Cause `explode();` makes an array from a string.

Comment: **making infinite recursion of a class in it** Sorry, i dont get it? splitt

Comment: A class which has itself in itself for an infinite ammount of depth. Better?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php  nope  only http://php.net/str_split  takses an string as first arg and in our code it will be an class instance  see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring   but have fun ;) but dont hurt your system :)

Comment: ** infinite** should not be within logical code. For what do you need ** infinite ammount of depth** ??

Comment: For nothing... for *fun* xD

Comment: if you want to do **strange things**   take look at this and make fun of it; `$variable = new stdClass(); $func = function($arg)use($variable){  /**/  }; $func($arg):`

Comment: I was playing around with recursions the whole day...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cxazjmoc0xn6ui/client.php?dl=0

Comment: Don't think I don't know what __toString does. I should remove it after having the `$this->string` as an instance of myself I wouldn't be able to get the original string out of it.

Comment: Sorry, too man lines too read. Late here. Hope helped a little, because its not really pointed out what your code really should do!

Comment: give a class that function and return 'Hello' and then print $obj;    you will see

Comment: JUST DO: $this->string = $string;   UPDATED

Comment: `PHPs OOP logic` and that is? , but before you answer: http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/   its little bit of time wsting to get angry about php or take too mutch notice on that. Keep hte Strange Stuff in Mind and make save code ;)

Comment: There are many more websites that shows the strangy behavior of php.

Comment: Last note on  __construct() `return false;` Constructor has no return value in php. Function maybe ends but no value is returned! 2 major bugs in your Constructor. Good Night!

Comment: Thank you... I saw this too, but I thought to let it like this. But I should throw an Exception there if it's not a string. Don't offend my skills ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70489/discussion-between-jankal-and-guest).

Comment: Ja, da ich jetzt gesehen hab an der email das du aus D kommst., nach kurz was auf deutsch: Der DropBox code is sehr komplex und sauber auf den ersten blick. Und hier sind  fehler im code. das mit dem `new tes(){}´ gibt es so in php nicht. Aber da du ja auch in D sitzt wie ich, vielleicht ne kleine pause oder morgen weiter machen ;;)

Comment: Gerne... da unterhält man sich mit Leuten auf English, nur weil man denkt, dass die kein deutsch können... Hab schon gedacht du wohnst in China oder so, weil du meintest, dass es spät sei...